# an UIButton in an UIPickerView doesn't respond to click event

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uipickerview

i add an UIButton to an UIPicker view bu this code

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {


UIView *returnedView=(id)view;
if (!returnedView) {


returnedView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, 44)];
}
returnedView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


 UILabel   *retval=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,50, 44)] autorelease];
      retval.text = [[_figureArrayPicker objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"FIGPic"];

      UIButton *button=[self  pieChartOfFigureWithCmm:row];
      [button setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 50, 44)];
      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(defectPressed:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
          [returnedView addSubview:button];

  } 

[returnedView addSubview:retval];


return returnedView;

}
```

but when i click on an uibutton this doesn't respond.
where was my mistake?
Thks.

Comment: Is your method definition for defectPressed: like -(void)defectPressed // callback for defectPressed or -(void)defectPressed:(id)sender// callback for defectPressed: Try checking the callback method.

Comment: - (IBAction) defectPressed: (id) sender
so like this i don't think there is porblem with the call.

Answer (score 0):

Just try explicitly changes  userInteractionEnabled=YES for button also, may that can be a case here.

Comment: the problem that when clicking on the button it becomes highlithed but doesn't call the correspondant method 
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(defectPressed:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory to your button.